# Inverter and main panel both have G-N bond. Best way to avoid ground currents?

Tags: inverter, grounding

I am using an inverter that internally bonds neutral and ground. It feeds a main panel via transfer switch (as required by code). Of course my main panel also bonds neutral and ground by code. The [inverter manual](https://www.renogy.com/content/RNG-INVT-2000-12V-P2/INVT-P2-Manual.pdf) gives the following justification:

> NEUTRAL and GROUND are bonded inside the inverter to comply with the National
> Electric Code (NEC) requirement that any AC source must have a neutral to ground
> connection.

Is the manual correct on this point? I thought the *main panel* was supposed to be the *sole* point of G-N bonding? However, assuming I connect each inverter terminal to the correspondingly named one on the main panel -- as recommended by the manufacturer -- this creates ground currents. As shown in the following drawing, there are now *two* G-N bonding points, effectively making both conductors into a single conductor and therefore sharing the return path current).

[image]

I'm pretty sure that ground currents are not allowed except by utility companies. The idea being that grounds *within a building* need to be at the same voltage for safety reasons. What is the best way to avoid ground currents if the inverter and main panel *both* bond G-N?

**Update** It was suggested to just add another switch pole for N. This may work in some situations, but I'd prefer a more general solution. For example, we may not have multiple neutral wires everywhere, as in the following situation.

[image]

Comment: Maybe ask the manufacturer or an electrician? How is the transfer switch wired, how does it switch live and neutral? Maybe the unit is not meat for permanent residential installations that connect to existing systems, but RVs and boats where the inverter itself is the mains source.

Comment: @Justme Good point that boats and RVs don't have a main panel with G-N bonding, explaining why the inverter would bond them.  The manual doesn't say you can't feed a building. But it does say "NEVER connect the AC output of the unit directly to an Electrical Breaker Panel/ Load
Centre which is also fed from the utility power / generator". Implying that the connection must be "indirect". Presumably because a direct connection to corresponding main panel terminals has the problem noted in the question. And yes the question is indeed how would an electrician solve the problem.

Comment: That might depend on your local electric code, so do you want a generic answer or a specific answer for your case which needs more details about your panel and switch are now wired?

Comment: @Justme I've added a wiring diagram. This is in the US (but that would be interesting if different jurisdictions had different solutions to this). Let me know if any more details are needed.

Comment: Maybe ask in DIY stack exchange. https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: It is definitely an electric code violation in the US to have two neutral/ground bonds active at the same time. But the situation with inverters can be complex. When they are in an RV or boat, they may be the only AC source and in that case it may be proper to bond neutral to ground. But what happens when you plug in shore power, which has its own neutral/bond? I think the newest inverters solved this with a relay that can connect or disconnect the ground bond when appropriate.

Comment: What's the load then? And why only the live is switched? For your diagram (if it is accurate enough) you can simply switch both line and neutral of the load and there is no problem, right? The inverter has mains sockets on it so that's why it must have internal bond.

Comment: @Justme *The inverter has mains sockets on it so that's why it must have internal bond.* That makes sense. I'm asking the generic way to break that bond when we no longer want it. Your suggestion to switch the neutral indeed seems to work in the first example I drew. Though it doesn't seem ideal (for cost reasons) nor general (I've added another drawing to show an example where it doesn't work).

Comment: @mkeith disconnectable G-N bond makes sense. Is there a standard way to retrofit this feature on an inverter that doesn't have it? Maybe just isolate the chassis with ceramic standoffs, and fuse the neutral (to prevent battery isolation faults from roasting the unprotected G-N loop)?

Comment: Many or most generators can be unbonded. Maybe your inverter can too if you take it apart.

Comment: @personal_cloud Of course you can always find an invalid scenario, when we update our suggestions. But isn't your load transfer switch then invalid if it does not switch the neutral? A general answer would be to have a suitable generator, suitable load switch and suitable wiring, not tricks and hacks of modifying randomly selected unsuitable equipment.

Comment: There are transfer switches available that switch neutral, ground, and both hot wires (4 pole switch). They would be used when both AC sources have bonds. But most transfer switches pass neutral and GND straight through (two pole switch). I can't tell you what to do. But most standby generators have neutral bonded to ground internally, and people connect them to their house with a two pole switch anyway, thus introducing a second bonding point and violating the electrical code.

Comment: I definitely think you should ask this question on the DIY stack exchange though, and close it out here (delete it). Of course search DIY stack exchange first to see if it has been addressed before.

Comment: @Justme *A general answer would be to have a suitable generator, suitable load switch and suitable wiring...* Sure. *not tricks and hacks of modifying randomly selected unsuitable equipment....* Sure. My question is how to *properly* modify equipment that can easily be made suitable. (Of course it would be even better if the equipment did not require modification, but that's a shopping question, which therefore is not appropriate for any SE site).

Comment: @personal_cloud What if there is no way to **properly** modify them, as you need electrical safety and compliance with local electrical codes for **properly** doing whatever you want to do.

Comment: @Justme *What if there is no way to properly modify them, as you need electrical safety and compliance with local electrical codes for properly doing whatever you want to do.* That would be a fine answer, if you can elaborate it. However, at the moment I don't see the need for additional wiring or switched neutrals, given the existence of inverters that don't require such things.

Comment: The other thing is, you could just unbond the neutral to ground bond in your main panel. Let the inverter supply the ground/netural bond for the whole installation. Not sure it is code compliant but at least you would only have one bond. If you ever disconnect the inverter you would have to remember to redo the bond inside the main panel.

Comment: @mkeith *Let the inverter supply the ground/neutral bond for the whole installation.* [NEC 250.142](https://ecuip.com/10-nec-codes-every-installer-should-know/) specifies that G-N bonding should occur either in the utility, or "within the enclosure of the AC service disconnecting means." Given this, letting the inverter G-N bond everything doesn't sound code compliant to me. (Also it doesn't scale to multiple inverters, and unbonding the main panel sounds like a lot more work than unbonding the inverter. And how would somebody keep track of this in case the inverter is removed later?)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is more of a building code question than it is an electronics design question.